# invalid operands to binary expression (string to string (aka basic string))

Tags: c++

I get this problem when trying to input a string in a constructor of my class Personne :

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') and 'string')
```

Here are my Files :

Personne.hpp :

```
#ifndef Personne_hpp
#define Personne_hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Personne{
protected:
string nom;
string prenom,cin,adresse;
public:
// constructeur par défaut:
Personne();
// constructeur par valeur:
Personne(string,string,string,string);
// presenter personne:
void presenter();
// Destructeur:
virtual ~Personne();
};
#endif /* Personne_hpp */
```

Personne.cpp:

```
#include "Personne.hpp"

// constructeur :
Personne::Personne(){
    cout<<"entrez le nom de la personne: " <<endl;
    cin>>this->nom;
    cout<<"entrez le prenom de la personne: "<<endl;
    cin>> this->prenom;
    cout<<"entrez le cin de la personne: "<<endl;
    cin>> this->cin;
    cout<<"entrez l'adresse de la personne: "<<endl;
    cin>> this->adresse;
}
```

Comment: This is but one of the reasons [why “using namespace std” is considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Pretty convincing, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a name collision in your class between std::cin and your member string cin.  Rename the member.

Comment: And stop using `using namespace std`

Comment: thank you I just find it more easy to write.. does it make a lot of problems to use the namespace instead of std:: ?

Comment: In the grand scheme of things no... But, as you just experienced, it can cause confusion...